# Is Manaka and Hikari more deeply connected to the Sea God and the Lady Jojoshi?

Tags: nagi-no-asukara

In episode 26 near the beginning when Manaka is talking about the Sea God and the Lady Jojoshi there is a shot of the Lady Jojoshi walking up to the Sea God with 2 children, one looks like a young Manaka and the other looks like a young Hikari.

Is this an indication that Manaka and Hikari are more deeply connected to the Sea God as the Lady Jojoshi?

Comment: Are you talking about descendancy?

Comment: @Mindwin that or reincarnation or anything else which explains why a young Manaka and Hikari are seen with the Lady Jojoshi

Comment: I think this has to do with Shintoism.